# Form Option in PHP to Post to MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, input

I have a form in HTML / PHP that posts the information to a MySQL Database. I have ran into a problem now since everything before was just a "input type="text" - and now I want to do a drop down option to select. I am trying but it does not work.

Here is the code on the form: If you need the other PHP file that displays the data and if it will help then please let me know and I will update it.

It is the Select Name = Track that I want to make a drop down. Only thing is the value of the text areas is one set thing in PHP. For the script to work right and post whatever is selected from the drop down, will I have to make each one of those in my Database also ? Please help me out. I cannot figure this one out and make it work. Thank you all in advance!

```
 <form action="" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
 <div>
 <p><strong>ID:</strong> <?php echo $id; ?></p>
 <strong>First Name: </strong> <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $first; ?>" /><br/>
 <strong>Last Name: </strong> <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $last; ?>" /><br/>
 <strong>Address: </strong> <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $address; ?>" /><br/>
 <strong>City: </strong> <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $city; ?>" /><br/>
 <strong>State: </strong> <input type="text" name="st" value="<?php echo $st; ?>" /><br/>
 <strong>Zip: </strong> <input type="text" name="zip" value="<?php echo $zip; ?>" /><br/>
 <strong>Phone Number: </strong> <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" /><br/> 
 <strong>Drivers License: </strong> <input type="text" name="dl" value="<?php echo $dl; ?>" /><br/>
 <strong>Email Address: </strong> <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" /><br/> 
 <strong>Track Name: </strong>
<select name="Track">
<option value="hillclimb">HillClimb</option>
<option value="trioval">Tri-Oval</option>
<option value="pulpfiction">Pulp Fiction</option>
<option value="speeddrome">SpeedDrome</option>
<option value="roadptc">Road PTC</option>
<option value="tubby">Tubby</option>
</select>
<br />
 <strong>Lane Color: </strong> <input type="text" name="lane" value="<?php echo $lane; ?>" /><br/> 
 <strong>Car Number: </strong> <input type="text" name="car" value="<?php echo $car; ?>" /><br/> 
 <strong>Controller Number: </strong> <input type="text" name="controller" value="<?php echo $controller; ?>" /><br/>  

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

 </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Do you want to create dropdown with php code, or it can remain as it is? Php code should be fine.

Comment: it shows the dropdown. But when I select the dropdown option I want it will not add that selected item to the database and save it.

Comment: what is your php to get the selected value? ie. `$Track = $_POST['Track']` ? If your mysql table column is something like `\`Track\` VARCHAR(15)`, you should be able to insert any of the selected values.

Comment: You need: one additional database field, and, as Sean suggested - proper code to accept Track value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the PHP code that processes this form result.

My guess is that in PHP, you're using all lowercase (like the rest of your form fields, "firstname", "lastname", "zip", etc..), yet the drop-down for track starts with a capital letter: "Track"